# Reduce problem to max flow

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, network-flow, discrete-optimization

I have the following question:

> Assume each student can borrow at most 10 books from the library, and the library has three copies of each title in its inventory. Each student submits a list of books he wishes to borrow. You have to assign books to students, so that a maximal number of volumes is checked out.

I was wondering whether this is a Max Flow problem? If so, should it be set out like this?

[image: Directed acyclic graph]

Would a greedy algorithm work here? Simply, pick a student and assign whatever books are applicable to him and then move on to the next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your characterization of the problem into a max flow problem seems correct to me: make a vertex for each student, a vertex for each book listed, and a source and a sink.  Connect the source to each student with a capacity of 10, connect each student to his desired books with a capacity of 1, connect each book to the sink with a capacity of 3.

However, a greedy algorithm will not work for network flow problems.  Here is a lecture explaining the Ford Fulkerson algorithm, and it gives an example where a greedy approach doesn't work: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*G6*-ljgmXE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_G6_-ljgmXE)

---

An example of lists where a greedy algorithm won't work:

Student 1, 2, and 3 all ask for books 1 through 11.  Student 4 only asks for books 1 throough 10.

A greedy algorithm gives students 1, 2, and 3 the first 10 books and none to the fourth so 30 books are checked out.  It is possible to give the first 3 students books 2 through 11 and the fourth student book 1, which checks out 31 books.

Comment: How would you constrain the flows to be discrete values?

Comment: 1, 10, and 3 are discrete values.

Comment: The capacities are discrete, but does that necessarily result in discrete answers?

Comment: The optimal answer will be an integer.  All of the graph cuts will have integer capacities, so by the min-cut max-flow theorem the maximum flow will also be an integer.  I'm working on an example where a greedy algorithm won't work btw, I believe the key is that the student can submit a list with more than 10 books.

Comment: Found it: Integral Flow Theorem.